# What are the role of titles before names in English?

Tags: politeness, proper-nouns, parsing

For example:

> Mr. Chan
>
> Chef Akbar
>
> President Obama
>
> Doctor Tom

My question is what are these titles, that is Mr, chef, president and doctor, called in English during parsing? Are they an adjective or a determiner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called **"english honorifics"**, or simply **"honorifics"**. They are usually placed inmediately before a person's name and they serve as titles to many purposes, mostly to convey esteem or show respect when addressing or referring to a person. I give you some examples:

1. Formal titles (Mr, Mrs, Sir, Madam, etc).
2. Occupations (Dr, Captain, Coach, Professor, PhD, etc).
3. Religious organizations (Reverend, Father, Brother, etc).
4. Royalty - these are very particular, since they act as a complete replacement for the person's name (Your Majesty, Your Honour, Your Royal Highness, etc)

You can refer to [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorific#Modern_English_honorifics) and [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_honorific) links for more info about them.

Comment: gr8 answer. And could you recommend me how to parse them? are they an adjective, appositive, what?

Comment: The best fit is that they are adjectives.

Comment: EDIT: The best fit is that they are adjectives. Honorific an personal titles are considered adjectives when they are attached to a name (according to Grammar monster at [here](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/adjectives.htm) ). I consider this is right, since they are acting as adjectives describing the social status or occupation of the person.